# Error downloading pip Package on my macOS Mojave

Tags: python, macos, pip

Im trying to download pip on my macOS Mojave with two different ways and im getting the bellow error's

**First way** .

I'm Downloading get-pip.py file from the pip website and in terminal  im typing **sudo python get-pip.py** and im getting this error :

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
>   [Error Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG8Xy.png)

**Second way**

Im trying to download pip with **sudo easy_install pip** command in my terminal and im getting this error

> error: [Errno 17] File exists: '/usr/local/bin'
>   [Error Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Avtv.png)

Please if anyone knows the solution please let me know ,
Thanks

Comment: `pip` is already installed on your machine.

Comment: it seems pip is already on your machine maybe go into the /usr/local/bin and see if there is a pip file if there is maybe uninstall it and then reinstall it again.

Comment: Thanks for the rensponse , i'm trying to run a pip command but command not found , so im guessing that i dont have the pip installed